# reading in jSON data with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, parsing, google-maps-api-2

Trying to read in some information from the google maps api into my application with JS. But havent quiet got my head around accessing the information in the returned jSON object.
 My JS is...

```
        var site = "./maps/scripts/reverseGeocode/locale.php";
        var params = "lat="+lat+"&"+"lng="+lng;

        var object = system.functions().ajax(site, params);

            var result = object.address_components[0];

          alert(result);
```

The jSON object is as follows...

```
  {
    "results" : [
      {
     "address_components" : [
        {
           "long_name" : "24",
           "short_name" : "24",
           "types" : [ "street_number" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Carabella St",
           "short_name" : "Carabella St",
           "types" : [ "route" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Kirribilli",
           "short_name" : "Kirribilli",
           "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "New South Wales",
           "short_name" : "NSW",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Australia",
           "short_name" : "AU",
           "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "2061",
           "short_name" : "2061",
           "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
        }
     ],
     "formatted_address" : "24 Carabella St, Kirribilli NSW 2061, Australia",
     "geometry" : {
        "bounds" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : -33.84886950,
              "lng" : 151.21871730
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : -33.84960880,
              "lng" : 151.21810640
           }
        },
        "location" : {
           "lat" : -33.84892950,
           "lng" : 151.21817770
        },
        "location_type" : "RANGE_INTERPOLATED",
        "viewport" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : -33.84789016970850,
              "lng" : 151.2197608302915
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : -33.85058813029150,
              "lng" : 151.2170628697085
           }
        }
     },
     "types" : [ "street_address" ]
  },
  {
     "address_components" : [
        {
           "long_name" : "Kirribilli",
           "short_name" : "Kirribilli",
           "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "New South Wales",
           "short_name" : "NSW",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Australia",
           "short_name" : "AU",
           "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "2061",
           "short_name" : "2061",
           "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
        }
     ],
     "formatted_address" : "Kirribilli NSW 2061, Australia",
     "geometry" : {
        "bounds" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : -33.84245090,
              "lng" : 151.22032150
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : -33.85270230,
              "lng" : 151.21152060
           }
        },
        "location" : {
           "lat" : -33.84753980000001,
           "lng" : 151.21314540
        },
        "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
        "viewport" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : -33.84245090,
              "lng" : 151.22032150
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : -33.85270230,
              "lng" : 151.21152060
           }
        }
     },
     "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
  },
  {
     "address_components" : [
        {
           "long_name" : "2061",
           "short_name" : "2061",
           "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "New South Wales",
           "short_name" : "NSW",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Australia",
           "short_name" : "AU",
           "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        }
     ],
     "formatted_address" : "New South Wales 2061, Australia",
     "geometry" : {
        "bounds" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : -33.84234370,
              "lng" : 151.22032150
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : -33.85270230,
              "lng" : 151.20932150
           }
        },
        "location" : {
           "lat" : -33.84839570,
           "lng" : 151.21461550
        },
        "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
        "viewport" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : -33.84234370,
              "lng" : 151.22032150
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : -33.85270230,
              "lng" : 151.20932150
           }
        }
     },
     "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
  },
  {
     "address_components" : [
        {
           "long_name" : "New South Wales",
           "short_name" : "NSW",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Australia",
           "short_name" : "AU",
           "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        }
     ],
     "formatted_address" : "New South Wales, Australia",
     "geometry" : {
        "bounds" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : -28.15619210,
              "lng" : 153.63873290
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : -37.50503180,
              "lng" : 140.99921220
           }
        },
        "location" : {
           "lat" : -31.25321830,
           "lng" : 146.9210990
        },
        "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
        "viewport" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : -28.15619210,
              "lng" : 153.63873290
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : -37.50503180,
              "lng" : 140.99921220
           }
        }
     },
     "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
  },
  {
     "address_components" : [
        {
           "long_name" : "Australia",
           "short_name" : "AU",
           "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        }
     ],
     "formatted_address" : "Australia",
     "geometry" : {
        "bounds" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : -9.22108360,
              "lng" : 159.10545890
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : -54.77721850,
              "lng" : 112.92145430
           }
        },
        "location" : {
           "lat" : -25.2743980,
           "lng" : 133.7751360
        },
        "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
        "viewport" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : -9.22108360,
              "lng" : 159.10545890
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : -54.77721850,
              "lng" : 112.92145430
           }
        }
     },
     "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
  }
  ],
  "status" : "OK" 
 }
```

I am trying to access the address component... but am unsure how to traverse the object correctly.. could someone help me.

```
           "long_name" : "Kirribilli",
           "short_name" : "Kirribilli",
```

Comment: yes this is my home address... please do not stalk me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
var long_name = object.address_components[2].long_name;
var short_name = object.address_components[2].short_name;
```

EDIT: suggest you use jquery ajax instead for the fetch:

```
var site = "./maps/scripts/reverseGeocode/locale.php";
var params = "lat="+lat+"&"+"lng="+lng;

$.get(site + '/' + params, function(data) {
    var long_name = data.address_components[2].long_name;
    var short_name = data.address_components[2].short_name;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response... it return object.address_components is undefined. This is the problem I had... its kinda curious any thoughts?

Comment: thanks helk but am trying to avoid jQuery for this type of thing.

Comment: then you have to decode json the old fashion way =) here is a tutorial http://www.json.org/js.html

Comment: here is a good tutorial for ajax calls without jQuery: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_aspphp.asp